# Why is $0$ excluded from the definition of the projective space?

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

I have a follow-up question to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93956/why-is-0-excluded-in-the-definition-of-the-projective-space-for-a-vector-space).

We define $\mathbb{P}^n\mathbb{C}$ as $(\mathbb{C}^{n+1}-\{0\})/(a\sim ta)$. So, if we include $0$ in our definition, then we will have that all points are equivalent to $0$ as
$$ta\sim a\sim 0\cdot a\sim 0$$
i.e. we will have one equivalent class. Also, more geometric explanation: projective space is the space of lines, but $0$ is not a line.

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, the projective space is the space of lines and $0$ is not a line. You can include $0$ as a point without using it as a scalar but then e.g. the result will fail to be a manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the relation is $v \sim w \iff \exists \hspace{0.1cm} \lambda \in \mathbb{K}^{*} = \mathbb{K}-\left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace : w = \lambda w$. So $v \sim 0 \iff \exists \hspace{0.1cm} \lambda \in \mathbb{K}^{*} : 0 = \lambda v$, but $\lambda \ne 0$, do you see what happens ?

Comment: Oh, it does make sense. So, the point is that we do rescaling by a non-zero constant. Thanks!