# Find the points at infinity of $3x − 7y +5 = 0$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, projective-geometry

I am trying to understand the method of finding the points at infinity of elliptic curves. There are [good questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13763/elliptic-curves-and-points-at-infinity) that deal with the general theory of doing this, but I couldn't find any good examples.

I understand the following question:

> $$C: x^22 + xy − 2y^2 + x − 5y +7=0$$

Homogenizing we find
$$C: X^2 + XY - 2Y^2 + XZ - 5YZ + 7Z^2 = 0.$$
To find the points at infinity on $C$, we substitute $Z=0$ and solve:
$$X^2 + XY - 2Y^2 = 0$$
Factoring, we have
$$(X + 2Y)(X - Y) = 0 \text {, so } X = -2Y \text { or } X = Y \text {.}$$
Thus, there are two points at infinity on $C,[-2,1,0]$ and $[1,1,0]$. These correspond to the "directions" in the affine plane given by the lines $x=-2 y$ and $x=y$.

I'm confused on how to use this method to find the points at infinity of an even simpler equation. Take

> $$C_0: 3x - 7y + 5 = 0$$

Homogenizing and taking $Z=0$ just yields $0=0$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 3x-7y+5=0 is not the equation of a curve but of a planar surface.

Comment: Sure, how does that change finding the points at infinity?

Comment: Homogenizing the equation yields $3X - 7Y + 5Z = 0$. Now set $Z = 0$.

Comment: @WindSoul $3x - 7y + 5 = 0$ is the equation of a line in the (affine) plane. A line is a type of curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homogenizing we find
$$3X - 7Y + 5Z = 0.$$
Taking $Z=0$ we have
\begin{align*}
   3X - 7Y &=0 \\
   3X &= 7
\end{align*}
so $X = \frac{7}{3}Y$ which yields the point at infinity $\left[\frac{7}{3}, 1, 0\right]$.

Comment: The points $\left[\frac{7}{3} Y : Y : 0\right] = \left[\frac{7}{3} : 1 : 0\right]$ are equal for all $Y \neq 0$; this is part of the definition of projective space. There is only one point on this line at infinity. This should be intuitive: the line at infinity and any other line intersect in exactly one point.